# Turtle Colision

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making a game using the turtle module, and want to detect colision betwen the original and the clone.I have tried saving the position of the clone, and then checking if the original has the same position, but the turtle only detects the clone if it has the exacly same position. Is there another way to detect colisions?

```
  import turtle
import time
import random
points = 0
t = turtle.Turtle()
sc = turtle.Screen()
turtle.bgcolor("black")
t.turtlesize(3)
c = t.clone()
c.goto(200, 200)
c.color("red")
c.turtlesize(1)
t.color("blue")
def turnleft():
    t.left(90)
def turnright():
    t.right(90)

while True:
    t.forward(10)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sc.onkey(turnleft, "Left")
    sc.onkey(turnright, "Right")
    sc.listen()
    # here is the no so working collision detector
    if t.pos() == (200, 200):
        points = (points + 1)
```

Comment: add code snippets to your question to get better help, it's unclear where exactly things are going wrong. From your description it sounds like it is correctly identifying where the original and clone overlap at the same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know about 2 ways of detecting collisions:

1. Distance-based collision detection: You can use the distance method to calculate the distance between two turtles. It's very simple and not verry accurate.

```py
import turtle
original = turtle.Turtle()
clone = original.clone()

clone.goto(100, 100)
distance = original.distance(clone)
if distance < 20:
    print("Collision detected!")
else:
    print("No collision.")
```

2. Rectangle-based collision detection. Use the bounding boxes of the turtles to detect collisions.

```py
def get_bounds(t):
    x, y = t.pos()
    w, h = t.shapesize()
    w *= 20
    h *= 20
    left = x - w/2
    right = x + w/2
    top = y + h/2
    bottom = y - h/2
    return left, right, top, bottom

def check_collision(t1, t2):
    l1, r1, t1, b1 = get_bounds(t1)
    l2, r2, t2, b2 = get_bounds(t2)
    if r1 >= l2 and l1 <= r2 and t1 >= b2 and b1 <= t2:
        print('collision detected')
```

Note that this is a sample code and I didn't test it properly. i found it in my notes.